# HTML5 - html, prefix and meta related

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to HTML5. I did some researches on prefix and OGP, but I still cannot figure out the following

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
    <title>something</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="something"/>
    <meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:image" 
    content="http://something.com/img/social-image.png" />
</head>
```

1. `<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">`What's `"og: http://ogp.me/ns#"`? What does it do?

I found this from quora (https://www.quora.com/What-does-this-tag-mean-html-lang-en-US-prefix-og-http-ogp-me-ns), but I cannot understand it.

> The Open Graph protocol enables any web page to become a rich object
>   in a social graph. For instance, this is used on Facebook to allow any
>   web page to have the same functionality as any other object on
>   Facebook.

What does "become a rich object" mean?

2.Why do we need these two lines, `<title>something</title>` and `<meta property="og:title" content="something"/>`? Aren't they same?

3.Why do we need to set the meta prefix again in the third line? Didn't we do it in the head?

```
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:image" 
    content="http://something.com/img/social-image.png" />
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

What you're describing is called Open Graph Protocol, and it essentially means you're using that template above to turn a webpage into a graph object. You need four parts: `og:title`, `og:type`, `og:url`, and `og:image`, which are described in detail [here](http://ogp.me/#). This is the basic metadata you need to use Open Graph Protocol - if you don't have it, Open Graph won't work.

Comment: is it valid to add the prefix in the `head` tag ?

Comment: thanks, so `<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">` is wrong if I undestand you well